# 1-to-1 mapping between rectangles in a square and points in a cube

Tags: geometry

I’m using the following mapping for a new tool I’m building, and I wanted to ask for references on prior art before publishing.  Thank you.

Is the following theorem a known result?  Are there any related theorems?

> Given an $s \times s$ square and an $s \times s \times s$ cube, there is a near 1-to-1 correspondence between points on the cube and rectangles of perimeter $2s$ contained in the square.  Horizontally reflected rectangles map to the same points when touching the left or right sides of the square.

For example, we can show this for $s=4$ below. Rectangles with a perimeter of $8$ are drawn inside a 4x4 square next to a 3-component bar chart corresponding to the mapped 3D point.  (The rectangles are highlighted with a round outline to make zero-height and zero-width rectangles visible.)

1. Zero-height rectangles:

   [image]
2. Zero-width rectangles:

   [image]
3. Rectangles with nonzero area:

   [image]
4. Shortening the rectangle decreases horizontal mobility:

   [image]

I hope the illustrations help.  I haven’t formally written out the whole thing yet, but I appreciate any possibly related references.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pictures show that you use three parameters between $0$ and $s$ to determine the position of the rectangle in the square. (I could probably figure out what they represent, but there is no need to.)

As you note, for all but a  few known special cases each set of parameters determines a unique rectangle.

I don't think  you need any references to prior art to proceed with this mapping.

Comment: Adding to this: it makes sense that three parameters are sufficient, since for arbitrary rectangles it would be four (the distances from each wall, say) but fixing the perimeter reduces the dimension by 1.